# Зависимости подпроектов

Tags: c++, cmake, lib

Решил разбить свой проект на несколько подпроектов cmake (статических библиотек .lib).
Сделал как в примерах: подпапки - подпроекты cmake.
Сразу скажу, что мой приоритетный компилятор - Visual Studio 2013.

И вот я такой счастливый наплодил статических библиотек - mylib1, mylib2, mylib3.

И захотел собрать 2 программы из них

**myappA** (mylib1+mylib2)

**myappB** (mylib2+mylib3).

И тут **внезапно** при сборке приложения **myappA** оказалось, что mylib1, помимо всего прочего, зависит от zlib, shell32 и для пущего эффекта libboost (к примеру).

Вот только на этапе сборки приожения **myappA** линкер ничего об этом не знает и вываливает кучу ошибок. И как ему сообщить о зависимостях красивым способом, мне непонятно. Ну то есть можно вручную прописать, но может быть есть более элегантный способ передать зависимости?

P.S. В случае .dll-библиотек и cmake всё гораздо проще.

Answer (score 3):

На мой взгляд, именно явное прописывание зависимостей и будет наиболее элегантным решением. Вы можете создать переменную, со списком зависимостей для каждой библиотеки и уже использовать эту переменную как в самой библиотеке, так и в генерации бинарника.

Есть и другой способ,— генерация большой библиотеки из всех имеющихся малых. Это уже зависит от платформы и, соответственно, cmake файл будет больше и сложнее. Как это сделать можно посмотреть, например, [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14199708/cmake-include-library-dependencies-in-static-lib); там есть решение и для gcc и для студии.